# Pdfs not displaying in fancybox 2 iframe in IE9, 10 and 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

I have pdfs successfully loading in Fancybox 2 iframes for Google Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox and IE 8. However, the iframe is empty for IE 9, 10 and 11. Does anyone have a solution for loading pdfs in a Fancybox 2 iframe, specifically for IE9, 10 and 11? The iframe displays, but is empty and there is a question at the bottom of the page asking if you want to open or save the pdf. If you select open, a new window opens and displays the pdf (not in the iframe). The website uses HTML5 & CSS3. Here is some of the code:

HTML code page:

```
<!doctype html>

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="PDFs/myfile.pdf"></a>
```

Script on HTML code page (sorry, but I can't seem to get this to line up correctly in my post):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
       width : "85%",
       height : "80%",
 autoSize: false,
 iframe : {
    preload: false,
 'content': '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />'      
       }
     });
 });
 </script>
```

I have searched through many already asked questions for a solution, tried many suggestions and still cannot get the pdfs to display in IE 9, 10 or 11. Note: the "iframe preload: false" script did solve this issue in Google Chrome and IE8, so thank you for anyone who posted those suggestions.

Please help if anyone knows how to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't have an embedded pdf viewer like apple has. You need to use your own PDF.js implementation, if you want to display inline or possible make sure acrobat extensions are included and that your mime type is proper.